# iOS InApp receipt validation and unlock the app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

I'm validating receipts with the App Store for auto renewing subscription using my own server. And returns `status`, `receipt`, `latest_receipt`, `latest_receipt_info`, `latest_expired_receipt_info`, `pending_renewal_info` and `is-retryable` in response as mentioned in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW4). So after getting above response what are the parameters we need to check before unlock the app.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check if receipt status is valid. If the status code returns a value between 21100-21199 (Internal data access error), check is_retyrable flag. Make sure to retry in case the status is a retryable Internal data access error.

You also want to check the latest active receipt. latest_receipt_info includes the list of purchases. You should check end-date of the latest receipt and make sure that it is not in the past

(see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/expires_date_ms)